# Change CMD language permanently to english Windows10 (specifically, ping output)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, language

Since a long time its been bugging me that the language used for the outputs of my commands is German(my native language) and not English.

Thing I tried changing to English:

[image: language settings image]

The "- german" only shows that the keyboard layout is German

[image: system locale image]

[image: chcp ping is still German image]

As you can see, nothing seems to work, or am I missing something?

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Code pages and the system language are totally different things. You can't change the language for a single app. My way around this was to create another user, set the language to English and login or SSH (using Bitwise server/client) to that user. Otherwise to extract specific values you can write batch/scripts to be bilingual.

Comment: @LotPings i know they are 2 different things, i was only showing what i tried getting the output language for cmd to change